# Can i oracle C# connection without oracle client?

Tags: c#, oracle, oracleclient

I want to do oracle connection with C# but I want it without oracle client. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The oracle JDBC "THIN" client is a standalone pure java client so you don't need to install any native Oracle client (SQL*NET etc). Check http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html for Oracle 11, you want the ojdbc5.jar or ojdbc6.jar depending on if you're using Java5 or Java6.

If you are using another version of oracle, just google for instance "oracle 10g jdbc thin" for the Oracle 10 drivers (first hit when I search).

Comment: If you want it in C#, why did you ask for JDBC and tag your question JAVA?

Answer (score 0):

you need to have only the driver (jar). here is example:

```
Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//myserver:PORT/SID", "USER", "PASS");
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
```

Comment: Class.forName : which class? can you give some code sample ? thanks

Comment: how I can write my service_name instead of sid?